# How to measure an optical encoder resolution and gear ratio?

Tags: motor, odometry, rotation, quadrature-encoder

I've bought a DC geared motor with an optical encoder. The vendor didn't provide specification. I can read ***MITSUMI M25N-2R-14 2241*** and ***25GA-370-12V-330RPM*** on the motor. There are some pages on the internet about this motor with contradicting information that I can't trust. I need to find a practical method to find exact **gear ratio** and **encoder resolution**.

[image]

I took a picture of the encoder and in a CAD software measured 1 degree the angle between two lines. I'm not sure about accuracy of this method!

[image]

I use this code in Arduino:

```
#include <Encoder.h>

Encoder myEncoder(2,3); // Best Performance     2, 3   intrupt
double Position ;
    
void setup() {
Serial.begin(250000) ;
Serial.println("Encoder Test.") ;
}
long oldPosition = -999 ;
void loop() {
long newPosition = myEncoder.read() ;
if (newPosition != oldPosition){
oldPosition = newPosition ;
Serial.println(newPosition);
}}
```

I can read data from my encoder but **how can I use this data**?

Comment: I don't know the gear ratio, it makes it hard to check visually. I have another problem with the encoder. it works fine when I test it manually (turning shaft with hand when the motor is off)  but shows random pulses when the motor is running!

Comment: oh, looking at the other end! that is right but this a small motor... I will try!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* 2012User. On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information rather than adding comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).

Comment: It seems like those labels are for 2 different motors

Comment: @guero64 one is related to encoder one is for the motor.

Comment: If you look up the part numbers, they are both for different motors.  I can see why it is confusing.